# Why this jquery selector does not work?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a task from a client to correct a page and I found that jQuery descendant selector does not behave as expected.

Here is an excrept of the HTML:

```
<form action="http://submit.url/subscribe.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="mssysform8217" class="mssysform" >
<div id="mssys-formcontainer">
    <div class="formfields">
        <table style="width: 100%">
        <div class="formfield-item" id="formfield-item-email">
            <tr>
            <td class="style1"><label >E-mail címe</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="">
                <div class="error-container">Please fill in this field!</div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I tried to debug it with FireFox:

- this worked:

  ```
  console.debug($("#mssysform8217 :input[name='email']").val());
  ```

  test@gmail.com
- this did not worked:

  ```
  console.debug($("#mssysform8217 #formfield-item-email :input[name='email']").val());
  ```

  undefined
- but:

  ```
  console.debug($("#mssysform8217 #formfield-item-email"));
  ```

  [div#formfield-item-email.formfield-item]

The problem is that the submit script is generated by a third party app and it wants to use the 3 level descendant selector.

Comment: Why are you using multiple ID Selectors (“#id”)?

Comment: And there only seems to be one `<input>` descending from #formfield-item-email, so the [name] attribute selector would be unnecessary. `$('#formfield-item-email input').val()` should be all you need.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The jQuery selector you are trying to use will not work because the HTML is invalid.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
        <div class="formfield-item" id="formfield-item-email">
            <tr>
```

This is not valid HTML.  It is not valid to place a div (or any element other than `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`) in the middle of a table outside of a cell.

**This is valid:**

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Or this is valid:**

```
<table>
  <tr><td><div></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

---

**On a side note:** You are using the table to format your form.  Tables are meant for tabular data.  Using tables for layout is a bad idea in my book.  Use proper semantics for HTML elements (tables = tabular data, li=lists, div=page divisions, etc...).

Comment: *"It is not valid to place a div (or any element) in the middle of a table..."* The exceptions being `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.

Comment: th cannot be put directly in a table. It's a header *cell* and should always be inside a tr. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: thanks. the form is also autogenerated by 3rd party app, and I was not sure that the place of the div is allowed there or not.